# want to delete child, but not childs references to other objects

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say i have three objects:
user, box, products

the user has got a box, the box has references to different products that the user has got in his box.

the user can basically decide which products he wants to have in his box.

if i delete the user, i want the box to be deleted as well, but i do NOT want the products to be deleted.

how can i go about doing this in hibernate?

my attempt was this:

in the User.hbm.xml, have an entry

```
<many-to-one name="theBox" column="BOX"
    class="com.example.Box"
            unique="true" cascade="all"/>
```

however, that seems to want delete the products as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `cascade="all"`.  All means "All".  you can use `save, update`.  Check out the documentation on [transitive persistance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive).

From that documentation, you might want to try `cascade="persist,merge,save-update".`

Comment: and what should i use instead?

Comment: i have described above what i want to achieve